# Como fazer um arquivo .gitignore global

Tags: git

Posso ter um arquivo `.gitignore` global? Ou seja, que independente do projeto ele elimine por exemplo os arquivos do sistema operacional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim você pode criar regras de exclusão global para o seu usuário em sua máquina local. Essas regras serão validas para todos os repositórios apenas na sua máquina local, as regras de exclusão Global não refletirá nas outras cópias do repositorio que estão em outras máquinas.

Por exemplo, você pode criar o arquivo `.gitignore_global` e adicionar algumas regras a ele.

Para isso abra o terminal e digite o comando:

- No **Mac** e **Linux**: `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`
- No **Windows**: 
  `git config --global core.excludesfile "%USERPROFILE%\.gitignore_global"`

Depois disso abra o seu editor de texto favorito e coloque suas regras de exclusão como um arquivo `.gitignore` recomendo que utilize as regras do gerador de arquivo `.gitignore` **gitignore.io**:

- **Mac** https://www.gitignore.io/api/macos
- **Windows** https://www.gitignore.io/api/windows
- **Linux** https://www.gitignore.io/api/linux.

Fonte: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/